# unable load selenium-webdriver on mac os el capitan

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, capybara, osx-elcapitan

I upgraded to El Capitan then problem started. When I run `cucumber features` it gives following error:

```
Background: Member should open homepage # features/m001_top_header.feature:6
Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load `selenium-webdriver`, please install the gem and add `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` to your Gemfile if you are using bundler. (LoadError)
./features/support/env.rb:47:in `new'
./features/support/env.rb:47:in `block in <top (required)>'
./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:22:in `Before'
Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load `selenium-webdriver`, please install the gem and add `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` to your Gemfile if you are using bundler. (LoadError)
./features/support/env.rb:47:in `new'
./features/support/env.rb:47:in `block in <top (required)>'
./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:22:in `Before'
```

when I run `bundle install` then `selenium-webdriver` is installed:

```
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) bundle install
...
Using websocket 1.2.2
Using selenium-webdriver 2.48.1
Using spec 5.3.4
...
Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 61 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) bundle show selenium-webdriver
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1
```

But when I check the `which selenium-webdriver`, it returns nothing:

```
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) which selenium-webdriver
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) which rspec
/usr/local/bin/rspec
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) which selenium-webdriver
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=)
```

My ruby version is:

```
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

I guess the problem is related to path and configuration because I can require `selenium-webdriver` irb,  but I couldnt solve it. Any gurus please help me on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May someone need this solution.

After many trials, eventually I found something solves the problem. First the version of `rbenv` and `ruby` were different so install the same version of ruby with rbenv as `ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`. After that install the `bundle` again and finally `bundle install` installed the webkit and other gems successfully.

```
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) rbenv version
2.0.0-p645 (set by /Users/mesutgunes/.rbenv/version)
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) bundle install
Failed to execute process '/usr/local/bin/bundle'. Reason:
The file '/usr/local/bin/bundle' specified the interpreter '/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby', which is not an executable command.
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=)
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=)
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.10.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.10.6
1 gem installed
~/P/m/web-automation (responsive ⚡=) bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

Comment: I need to use cucumber beacuse CI scripts depend on it.

Comment: huh?  bundle exec cucumber just sets up the environment so the specified version of gems in your Gemfile are being used, and then executes cucumber in that environment.

Comment: I know it runs the cucumber but I need to run `cucumber ... `

Comment: well unless the  cucumber executable you're running is setup as a binstub (which basically does bundle exec cucumber ... ) you're bypassing the environment set in your Gemfile and you're going to have all sorts of issues since you'll never be able to guarantee which version of an installed gem you're running